# curl (7) permission denied on cgi script

Tags: permissions, wget, curl, selinux

Can't understand which permissions could be denied. Running cgi script from command line works fine.

```
http_proxy="" curl http://url/ -o file
```

Produces `curl(7): permission denied`

(same issues with `wget`)

**EDIT (Workaround)**
Right now I have to partially disable SELinux to get this to work (tried twiddling all the permissions to no avail).

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Even though running script as `apache` from the command-line works, `SELinux` seems to be stopping `curl` and `wget` when cgi script is invoked through the web.

Edit `/etc/selinux/config`, change `SELINUX=permissive` (FYI: this has consequences)

Looking for a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with SELinux blocking curl calls from CGI. The best way to counter this is:

1. Reproduce the issue so that it is logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`
2. Parse the log to create a module:

   ```
   $ tail /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M curlCgi
   ```
3. Load the generated module:

   ```
   $ /usr/sbin/semodule -i curlCgi.pp
   ```

---

More reading: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when a `systemd` daemon calls `/opt/dir/to/myscript.sh` on startup, which contains a `curl` command. Failed with error 7 just like OP.

I found [this excellent post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/) by the good folks at NGINX, from which I learned about `audit2why`, which is an excellent tool to help debug SELinux problems.

This is what I did:

1. Restart the offending daemon to replicate the problem
2. `# tail -n 10 /var/log/audit/audit.log` to list most recent issues
3. Found this line which is exactly why `curl` failed: `type=AVC msg=audit(162431xxxx.342:20yyyy7): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=xxxxxxx comm="curl" dest=443 scontext=system_u:system_r:fsdaemon_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0`
4. Copy the message code `162431xxxx.342:20yyyy7`
5. `# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep "162431xxxx.342:20yyyy7" | audit2why` to let it suggest which `sebool` needs to be enabled

```
        Was caused by:
        The boolean nis_enabled was set incorrectly.
        Description:
        Allow nis to enabled

        Allow access by executing:
        # setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

6. Run `# setsebool -P nis_enabled 1` as suggested, try again and the problem is no more!

---

Alright, admittedly this is still a hack and I too have very little experience with SELinux. But at least this is better, **much better** than disabling SELinux outright. So do your due diligence, and make sure you *ACTUALLY* understand the flag you're setting. Ultimately, you are responsible for your own security!